# GDPR compliance and using personal devices for work

Tags: europe, gdpr

As part of our work in a EU company, we are allowed to use our personal electronic devices (laptops, cell phones, etc.)

As part of the GDPR compliance, our IT admin asked us to provide him with the serial and model numbers of our personal devices.

Are those information considered personal when combined? Do we put additional personal data in danger, in our effort for GDPR compliance and protection of any kept personal data within the company?

Comment: Why would that be necessary for the GDPR?

Comment: @nvoigt IT tries to build a map where personal information might be stored through the company servers. The correct would be to build a policy of not using personal devices, but this would require them buying cell phones for several people that are traveling.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere you might be able to connect the serial number with the imsi and or phone number /person

Comment: I suggest you all withdraw from this and ask for a second company owned device

Comment: Why would anyone vote this down ?   it's a fascinating question

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I believe S/Ns are personal identifiable information (PII) information (at least in USA) https://piwik.pro/blog/what-is-pii-personal-data/  A company that has employees and already uses PII information of its employees (SSN, ...), an additional one PII would not make a difference if handled properly as the rest. Of course experts have to say more.

Comment: @Fattie - could it be fascinating and off-topic at the same time?

Comment: Yes and Yes !   :)

Comment: You should keep careful notes of all these investigations you are doing on your own company and the research you are doing on company time talking to IT etc,. perhaps even record them. Alone they don't mean much, but if you put them all together logically outlining the salient details and format it nicely, and then file complaints everywhere possible. Together they should be able to get you sacked.

Comment: @kilisi they are not investigations, they are more relaxed discussions with colleagues and IT. Small company culture permits that opinions are exchanged between different disciplines between breaks etc. If my opinions seem reasonable, IT takes them into account. No procedure to file complaints for IT issues especially if their resolution is ongoing and IT Has not finalized his position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information of this sort is usually gathered to make sure unauthorised access is not made and enable accurate network diagrams, either dynamic or static.

So your IT for instance might be gathering it so he/she can check MAC addresses against hardware if there is ever a need.

Eg. One of my networks has a dynamic map that will show me everyone who is connected in real time and what devices they are connected with.

Another will just show MAC address but I can match that to a person and a device if I need to.

Lots of other legitimate things can be done with this info, none of which should concern you unless you are raising flags on a firewall or something like that.

Comment: I agree that this can be done and will offer a tool to GDPR compliance, but in this specific case he tries to identify the devices that store are able to store personal information (emails, addresses) and are out of the IT’s jurisdiction. The problem for IT would come in case somebody steals my personal device so he steals several personal information. My question for sensitive information, is that IT could claim that my personal device belongs to the company (if I do not have a receipt available)

Comment: All devices connected to a company network are within IT jurisdiction to some extent. But why would they do that? And where would they get their receipt from?

Comment: I am just presenting a crazy scenario

Comment: Well, if we're talking crazy, maybe he is collecting that info and putting your laptop up for sale on his personal website, then if anyone shows interest, he'll see when you use it, wait until you go toilet, steal it and sell it.

Comment: "As part of the GDPR compliance" .. why or how would this be part of GDPR compliance??  That's the question!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The question was not set probably correctly. It is more giving more personal data for GDPR compliance . Is that necessary? To have my personal data appear in a network map.

Comment: What personal data? It's just serial number and model. It's normal to have an employees name on a network map. Comprehensive ones may include anything up to the asset tag of the monitor.... serial number and model could be used in a variety of ways, none that would include trying to pretend they belong to the company, companies have asset lists complete with receipts and other info, if anything it might be used to differentiate between personal devices and company assets.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes he mentioned that and the requested data appeared in a company spreadsheet as welll. IT people that are up to 3 in number would have access to those information

Comment: @joestrazzere it is just a discussion and for sure it is not illegal when those data are protected as part of a procedure. Just trying to find and compare different practices as other employees complained as well. With gdpr enacted everybody became extra sensitive ...